# Create Reusable ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I have a couple of similiar ASP.NET MVC projects (solutions). These projects have several identical Controllers/Views and _Layout (MasterPage). I would like to distinguish these identical elements into separate reusable project. Is it possible to create such reusable project in ASP.NET MVC? And which techniques I have to use for it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try MvcContrib Portable Area http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20Portable%20Area&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Can I separate my _Layout.cshtml to another project using this approach?

Comment: Haven't tested. Theoretically it could be possible. I'm sure You could set up to use no layout and you could do this from portable area, so it might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create template from your project http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx

For parell develop, better approach maybe is to organise your projects like here: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/09/organizing-asp-net-mvc-solutions/

Comment: I thinks it is bad idea to use such approach. Because I these reusable project has to be ability to be developed parallely

Comment: Look at my 2nd link, maybe it could help? Anyway you've post interested question. Im looking forward for other answers.